# Export project resources on runtime

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio, c++-cli, .net-4.8

I'm making a desktop application in Visual Studio 2017, .NET Framework 4.8 using C++/CLI.

I have added files as resources:

[image: Resources1]

They appear like this in solution explorer :

[image: solution_explorer_resources]

Problem : I have a button. On runtime, when I click the button I want the application to export these resources (with the correct extension as they appear in solution explorer) somewhere on the hard drive.

I have no clue on how to proceed despite googling.